# How to show result in new page when my javascript modify the html and display result of AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When i click button the page is modified by javascript but i cannot go back to initial page as modified result is on same page  .i want browser to consider modified page by javascript as new page so that i can go back to initial page.

```
<button onclick="showUser();">THANKS </button>

    function showUser() {
       var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

             fnc(this);
             var p=JSON.parse(this.responseText);


             }

             var para= document.createElement("p");
              para.setAttribute("id","dynamicpara")  ;
             para.innerHTML=p[1].name;
             var element=document.getElementById("STAR");
             element.appendChild(para);



          }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "getuse.php", true);
        xhttp.send(); 
    }
```

Comment: You want to crate a tab like feature?

Comment: i want that on click a new page is created in browser so that i go back or come back from browser back and forword button

Comment: You want to go back to the original page after being modified is the tabbed interface. It can be easily done in JavaScript.

Comment: https://tickety-boo-scratch.000webhostapp.com/index.html {click on first button and then on xiaomi and when u come back middle page is missing}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok you want to simply go back. I found this code in your JavaScript

```
 function myDivert(){
     window.location.href="https://tickety-boo-scratch.000webhostapp.com/index1.html";
 }
```

which is redirecing you to `index1.html` page. You can change it to

```
 function myDivert(){
     window.location.href="https://tickety-boo-scratch.000webhostapp.com";
 }
```

to go back to the original page. Note that `index.html` and `index1.html` are entirely different pages.

It seems that you want to keep the middle page after click and show more content. In that case you can simply append content to some div in the middle page.

**Edit**

I can not do exactly what you want to do but I give you the idea. In your way of doing the state changes are not represented by the URL. You want to do something called *deep linking*.

You can do this using `window.location.hash` but you need to change the URL accordingly so that the user can use the back or forward button to move to and fro and ajax modified (as you said) is still visible to the user.

But to complete this you need a timer that checks the hash.

This is the same as the tabbed interface for deep linking and you can achieve exactly what you want to do with this.

Comment: 1.index to AJAX modified page .2 AJAX page to index1 but when i come back from index1 to index  ajax modified pge is lost i want ajax modifid page as new page so that it cant be lost when i come back

Comment: i want a way to change modified page into new page. histrory.pushstate do change the pagename but show error when i comeback.